# OpenLayers 3: Overlay a TMS layer on a OSM layer

Tags: openlayers, tile-map-service

I'm a bit at a loss of configuring OpenLayers 3 to display a generated TMS layer (in 3857) on top of an OSM layer. You can see the parameters of the TMS layer [here](https://quadridcmmaps.blob.core.windows.net/tynset/basemap.xml).

This is what I have so far, but that's not doing much...

Anyone knows what wrong?

Here is a jsfiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/pieterdhondt/4snbzL1r/

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tms_resolutions_3857_tynset = [5.8135986328125, 2.90679931640625, 1.45339965820313, 0.726699829101563, 0.363349914550781, 0.181674957275391, 0.0908374786376953, 0.0454187393188477];
    var extent_3857_tynset = [8923848.54918488, 1199098.1904393, 8924597.49205864, 1199956.06726346];

    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            }),
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                preload: 1,
                source: new ol.source.TileImage({
                    crossOrigin: null,
                    extent: extent_3857_tynset,
                    tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
                        extent: extent_3857_tynset,
                        origin: [extent_3857_tynset[0], extent_3857_tynset[1]],
                        resolutions: tms_resolutions_3857_tynset
                    }),
                    tileUrlFunction: function (coordinate) {

                        if (coordinate === null) return undefined;

                        // TMS Style URL
                        var z = coordinate[0];
                        var x = coordinate[1];
                        var y = coordinate[2];
                        var url = 'https://quadridcmmaps.blob.core.windows.net/tynset/' + z + '/' + x + '/' + y + '.png';
                        return url;
                    }
                })
            })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [1200512.8002755763, 8925231.712804087],
            zoom: 14
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok found out about it!

The extent and the center was mixed up...

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4snbzL1r/2/ :)

Answer (score 1):

This should already be too late, but for anyone (like me) coming across this question, please check the below JSFiddle for avoiding a tileUrlFunction and go with a simpler way of just providing the url format.

https://jsfiddle.net/4snbzL1r/6/

Just provide the "url" option instead of tileUrlFunction like:

```
url: 'https://quadridcmmaps.blob.core.windows.net/tynset/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'
```